# Python Pandas applymap na_action argument is not being recognized

Tags: python, pandas

When I try to use the argument "na_action" in Pandas' applymap function I got this error:

> TypeError: applymap() got an unexpected keyword argument 'na_action'

Example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2.12], [3.356, 4.567]])  
>>> df.iloc[0, 0] = pd.NA  
>>> df.applymap(lambda x: len(str(x)), na_action='ignore')
```

---

**TypeError** . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  . . . . . . . . . . . . Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
1 display(df_copy)
2 df.iloc[0, 0] = pd.NA
----> 3 df.applymap(lambda x: len(str(x)), na_action = 'ignore')

TypeError: applymap() got an unexpected keyword argument 'na_action'

Could anyone help me?

Comment: you should update to pandas 1.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try checking the pandas version you are using. 'na_action' is available with the latest version.

Comment: Now I see. The argument 'na_action' starts with version 1.2.0 (December 26, 2020).

Comment: I have version 1.5.0 and still not working