# how can fix the error :TypeError: applymap() got an unexpected keyword argument 'na_action'

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have this code and this error. how can I fix it?

thank for your consideration.

here is my code:

```
id_cols = [k for k in df.columns if k.lower().endswith('id')]
id_cols.append('TaskState')
id_cols.append('isFraud')
df2 = df.copy()
df2[id_cols] = df2[id_cols].applymap(string_to_int, na_action='ignore')
# optional: convert nan to some int value (here: 0)
df2[id_cols] = df2[id_cols].fillna(0)
```

the error is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-ff17131be8ff> in <module>()
 25 id_cols.append('isFraud')
 26 df2 = df.copy()
---> 27 df2[id_cols] = df2[id_cols].applymap(string_to_int, na_action='ignore')
 28 # optional: convert nan to some int value (here: 0)
 29 df2[id_cols] = df2[id_cols].fillna(0)

TypeError: applymap() got an unexpected keyword argument 'na_action'
```

Comment: Check your pandas version. `na_action` was introduced in version 1.2 (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.2.0.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas applymap na\_action argument is not being recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65636365/python-pandas-applymap-na-action-argument-is-not-being-recognized)