# twarc2 csv returns TypeError: applymap() got an unexpected keyword argument 'na_action'

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, twarc2

I am trying to use twarc2 csv via the command line to convert a downloaded .jsonl file into a csv file. However running the required twarc2 csv command returns the following TypeError:  applymap() got an unexpected keyword argument 'na_action' (see attached picture).
I saw in a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65636365/python-pandas-applymap-na-action-argument-is-not-being-recognized) that updating pandas should help but the error occurs even after having updated pandas.
Also this is my first post on stack overflow so let me know if you need additional information.
Many thanks in advance!

[command line TypeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKne2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Update: The issue was my outdated python version 3.6 which didn't allow me to upgrade pandas to 1.2. Installing the latest python version 3.9 and running the script again did the trick.